# React Native ListView optimization / performance on iPhone 5

Tags: performance, listview, reactjs, react-native, realm

I am working on a React Native application.

1. I have a Scene with a [ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) with some Components inside.
2. Each one of the Components in the ListView can be marked as selected (or unmarked).
3. Once the Scene has focused in, I fetch the data and display those 500 Components.
4. I pass the props to each one of the Components in the [OnRenderRow](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow) method.

Ideally, every time I click on one of the Components I would save the id inside a dictionary in the state and then I would trigger the fetch (now cached) again. Once I fetch the 500 Components again OnRenderRow checks if the ids exist in the dictionary and sets the isSelected prop to true (React will take care of rendering as selected).

**Why I am fetching the data again?**

In order to refresh React Native's ListView the datasource has to be 'marked as dirty'.

If I would try to refresh the list by reusing the same dataSource:

```
this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource})
```

Since it's the same object it would not trigger any OnRenderRow. As far as I know the only way to force the update of the list is using:

```
ds.cloneWithRows(Array)
```

Which means it has to go through the whole 500 Components again *(Actually it parses them all but it renders them in small windows of 20 or so)*

This works pretty fast in the emulator but in the iphone5 it takes 2-3 seconds. I have the same problem with filtering.

**Is there any way to force the ListView onRenderRow without parsing the whole dataSource again?**

*Note: The problem could also be related to Realm Native, but since the second time I fetch the elements I am caching the query and the problem persists its not probably the cause of it.*

Comment: Have you tried optimizing your rowHasChanged?

Comment: @rclai rowHasChanged it's only triggered when the dataSource its different.